# Symfony2 , improve query performance

Tags: php, performance, symfony, doctrine, dql

Does anybody know how to improve performance of this query? 
I'm using **doctrine DQL model**, here's the code
(it takes 5-6 sec without pagination bundle)

**Controller:**

```
    $data = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getEntityManager('sparcs')
                ->getRepository('TruckingMainBundle:BCT_CNTR_EVENTS')
                ->findOperationReport(Convert::serializeToArray($request->getContent()));
```

**Repository method:**

```
 public function findOperationReport($condition = array()) {

  $data = $condition['record'];
  $move_types = array();

  $result = $this->createQueryBuilder("sp")
                    ->addSelect("sp");


  // move types
  if(isset($data['vessel_discharge'])) {
      //$move_types[] = $this->container->getParameter('MOVE_TYPE.VESSEL_DIS');
       $move_types[] = 'VY';
  }
  if(isset($data['vessel_loading'])) {
      //$move_types[] = $this->container->getParameter('MOVE_TYPE.VESSEL_LOAD');
       $move_types[] = 'YV';
  }      
  if(isset($data['truck_out'])) {
      $move_types[] = 'TC';
  }    
  if(isset($data['truck_in'])) {
      $move_types[] = 'CT';
  }  
  if(isset($data['stuffing'])) {
      //$move_types[] = 'CT';
  }  
  if(isset($data['unstuffing'])) {
      //$move_types[] = 'CT';
  } 
  if(isset($data['rail_in'])) {
      $move_types[] = 'YR';
  }  
  if(isset($data['rail_out'])) {
      $move_types[] = 'RY';
  } 
  if(count($move_types) > 0) {
       $result->andWhere('sp.move_type IN (:move_type)')
               ->setParameter('move_type',$move_types);

  } else {
      $result->andWhere("1 = 2");
  }

 //container types
 if(isset($data['empty']) && isset($data['full'])) {
     //skipping
 }
 elseif (isset($data['empty'])) {
    $result->andWhere('sp.ctnr_status = :ctnr_status')
           ->setParameter('ctnr_status',self::CTNR_EMPTY);
}
elseif (isset($data['full'])) {
    $result->andWhere('sp.ctnr_status = :ctnr_status')
           ->setParameter('ctnr_status',self::CTNR_FULL);

    if(isset($data['weight_from'])) {
        $result->andWhere("cast(replace([weight],',','.') as float) :weight_from")
               ->setParameter('weight_from',$data['weight_from']);
        echo 'weight from';
    }
    if(isset($data['weight_to'])) {
        $result->andWhere('sp.weight <= :weight_to')
               ->setParameter('weight_to',(string)$data['weight_to']);
    }

}       

/*
//excpetion
$result->andWhere('sp.move_type NOT IN (:move_type_not)')
       ->setParameter('move_type_not',array('TY','YT'));     

  */     
 if(isset($data['today']) || isset($data['yesterday'])) {
     //yesterday
     if(isset($data['yesterday'])) {
        $yesterday = new \DateTime(date("Ymd"));
        $interval = new \DateInterval("P1D");
        $interval->invert = 1;
        $yesterday->add($interval);
     }

     //yesterday + today
    if(isset($data['today']) && isset($data['yesterday'])) {
        $result->andWhere('sp.move_time >= :yesterday')
                ->setParameter('yesterday',$yesterday->format("Ymd000000"));
    } 
    elseif(isset($data['yesterday'])) {
        $result->andWhere('sp.move_time >= :yesterday_from AND sp.move_time <= :yesterday_to')
                ->setParameter('yesterday_from',$yesterday->format("Ymd000000"))
                ->setParameter('yesterday_to',$yesterday->format("Ymd235959"));
     }
     elseif(isset($data['today'])) {
        $result->andWhere("sp.move_time = :today")
                ->setParameter('today',date("Ymd000000"));   
     } 
    } 
    else {
       //date conditions
       $date_from =  new \DateTime(strtotime($data['date_from']));
       $date_to =  new \DateTime(strtotime($data['date_to']));

       $result->andWhere("sp.move_time >= :date_from")
               ->setParameter('date_from',$date_from->format("Ymd000000"));
       $result->andWhere("sp.move_time <= :date_to")
               ->setParameter('date_to',$date_to->format("Ymd235959"));
    }
    //booking
    if(isset($data['booking']) && !empty($data['booking'])) {
       $result->andWhere("sp.booking = :booking")
               ->setParameter('booking',$data['booking']);   
    }


    //is reffer
    if(isset($data['reefer'])) {
       $result->andWhere("sp.reefer_flag = :reefer")
               ->setParameter('reefer','Y');   
    }

    //is damage
    if(isset($data['damage'])) {
       $result->andWhere("sp.hazards <> ''");  //$result->expr()->neq("sp.hazards","")  
    }

    //specific_type
    if(isset($data['specific_type'])) {
        /*
        $result->andWhere("sp.equip_type <> :specific_type")
                 ->setParameter('specific_type',$data['specific_type']);
         *
         */
    }

    //specific_type
    if(isset($data['container_type_20']) && isset($data['container_type_40'])) {
        //$result->andWhere("sp.equip_type <> :specific_type")
        //         ->setParameter('specific_type',$data['specific_type']);
    }
    elseif(isset($data['container_type_20'])) {
              $result->andWhere($result->expr()->substring('sp.equip_type',1,1)." = :equip_type")
                       ->setParameter('equip_type',2);
    }
    elseif(isset($data['container_type_40'])) {
              $result->andWhere($result->expr()->substring('sp.equip_type',1,1)." = :equip_type")
                       ->setParameter('equip_type',4);
    }
   return $result->setMaxResults(30)->getQuery();
```

}

If I use KnpPaginationBundle ,then it takes more than 27 sec )

```
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $data,
            2/*page number*/,
            10/*limit per page*/
        );
```

I can execute a native sql query without KnpPaginatorBundle (and it takes 0.333 ms)

```
  //START
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getEntityManager('sparcs')->getConnection()->executeQuery (
    'SELECT *
        FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                         OVER (
                           ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS "doctrine_rownum",
                       b0_.id                   AS id0,
                       b0_.container            AS container1,
                       b0_.container_use_key    AS container_use_key2,
                       b0_.line                 AS line3,
                       b0_.billable_line        AS billable_line4,
                       b0_.move_time            AS move_time5,
                       b0_.move_type            AS move_type6,
                       b0_.pos_from             AS pos_from7,
                       b0_.pos_to               AS pos_to8,
                       b0_.rotation_nbr         AS rotation_nbr9,
                       b0_.from_che             AS from_che10,
                       b0_.to_che               AS to_che11,
                       b0_.from_che_kind        AS from_che_kind12,
                       b0_.to_che_kind          AS to_che_kind13,
                       b0_.from_che_op          AS from_che_op14,
                       b0_.to_che_op            AS to_che_op15,
                       b0_.pow                  AS pow16,
                       b0_.internal_truck       AS internal_truck17,
                       b0_.lifter               AS lifter18,
                       b0_.quay_crane           AS quay_crane19,
                       b0_.license_plate        AS license_plate20,
                       b0_.trucker_id           AS trucker_id21,
                       b0_.trucker_name         AS trucker_name22,
                       b0_.arrv_qual            AS arrv_qual23,
                       b0_.arrv_carrier         AS arrv_carrier24,
                       b0_.dept_qual            AS dept_qual25,
                       b0_.dept_carrier         AS dept_carrier26,
                       b0_.invoyage             AS invoyage27,
                       b0_.outvoyage            AS outvoyage28,
                       b0_.lloyds_code          AS lloyds_code29,
                       b0_.load_port            AS load_port30,
                       b0_.disch_port           AS disch_port31,
                       b0_.destination          AS destination32,
                       b0_.equip_type           AS equip_type33,
                       b0_.bundle               AS bundle34,
                       b0_.ctnr_category        AS ctnr_category35,
                       b0_.ctnr_status          AS ctnr_status36,
                       b0_.ctnr_stopped         AS ctnr_stopped37,
                       b0_.commodity            AS commodity38,
                       b0_.weight               AS weight39,
                       b0_.damage               AS damage40,
                       b0_.reefer_temp          AS reefer_temp41,
                       b0_.reefer_flag          AS reefer_flag42,
                       b0_.damage_details       AS damage_details43,
                       b0_.seal_1               AS seal_144,
                       b0_.railcar_id           AS railcar_id45,
                       b0_.dwell_time           AS dwell_time46,
                       b0_.special_stow         AS special_stow47,
                       b0_.service              AS service48,
                       b0_.booking              AS booking49,
                       b0_.release_note         AS release_note50,
                       b0_.cmr_number           AS cmr_number51,
                       b0_.forwarding_agent     AS forwarding_agent52,
                       b0_.cargo_agent          AS cargo_agent53,
                       b0_.invoice_number       AS invoice_number54,
                       b0_.invoice_status       AS invoice_status55,
                       b0_.last_flag            AS last_flag56,
                       b0_.sparcs_user          AS sparcs_user57,
                       b0_.program              AS program58,
                       b0_.id                   AS id59,
                       b0_.container            AS container60,
                       b0_.container_use_key    AS container_use_key61,
                       b0_.line                 AS line62,
                       b0_.billable_line        AS billable_line63,
                       b0_.move_time            AS move_time64,
                       b0_.move_type            AS move_type65,
                       b0_.pos_from             AS pos_from66,
                       b0_.pos_to               AS pos_to67,
                       b0_.rotation_nbr         AS rotation_nbr68,
                       b0_.from_che             AS from_che69,
                       b0_.to_che               AS to_che70,
                       b0_.from_che_kind        AS from_che_kind71,
                       b0_.to_che_kind          AS to_che_kind72,
                       b0_.from_che_op          AS from_che_op73,
                       b0_.to_che_op            AS to_che_op74,
                       b0_.pow                  AS pow75,
                       b0_.internal_truck       AS internal_truck76,
                       b0_.lifter               AS lifter77,
                       b0_.quay_crane           AS quay_crane78,
                       b0_.license_plate        AS license_plate79,
                       b0_.trucker_id           AS trucker_id80,
                       b0_.trucker_name         AS trucker_name81,
                       b0_.arrv_qual            AS arrv_qual82,
                       b0_.arrv_carrier         AS arrv_carrier83,
                       b0_.dept_qual            AS dept_qual84,
                       b0_.dept_carrier         AS dept_carrier85,
                       b0_.invoyage             AS invoyage86,
                       b0_.outvoyage            AS outvoyage87,
                       b0_.lloyds_code          AS lloyds_code88,
                       b0_.load_port            AS load_port89,
                       b0_.disch_port           AS disch_port90,
                       b0_.destination          AS destination91,
                       b0_.equip_type           AS equip_type92,
                       b0_.bundle               AS bundle93,
                       b0_.ctnr_category        AS ctnr_category94,
                       b0_.ctnr_status          AS ctnr_status95,
                       b0_.ctnr_stopped         AS ctnr_stopped96,
                       b0_.commodity            AS commodity97,
                       b0_.weight               AS weight98,
                       b0_.damage               AS damage99,
                       b0_.reefer_temp          AS reefer_temp100,
                       b0_.reefer_flag          AS reefer_flag101,
                       b0_.damage_details       AS damage_details102,
                       b0_.seal_1               AS seal_1103,
                       b0_.railcar_id           AS railcar_id104,
                       b0_.dwell_time           AS dwell_time105,
                       b0_.special_stow         AS special_stow106,
                       b0_.service              AS service107,
                       b0_.booking              AS booking108,
                       b0_.release_note         AS release_note109,
                       b0_.cmr_number           AS cmr_number110,
                       b0_.forwarding_agent     AS forwarding_agent111,
                       b0_.cargo_agent          AS cargo_agent112,
                       b0_.invoice_number       AS invoice_number113,
                       b0_.invoice_status       AS invoice_status114,
                       b0_.last_flag            AS last_flag115,
                       b0_.sparcs_user          AS sparcs_user116,
                       b0_.program              AS program117
                FROM   bct_cntr_events b0_
                WHERE  b0_.move_type IN ( \'YY\',\'YV\',\'VY\',\'TY\' )
                       AND b0_.move_time >= \'20120910000000\'
                       AND b0_.move_time <= \'20120912300000\') AS doctrine_tbl
        WHERE  "doctrine_rownum" BETWEEN 11 AND 20  '                    
                    )->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Think about add memcache as a cache driver.
2. Think about stopping hydrating results to entity objects (time & cpu consuming)

   $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
3. Avoid conditions with wildcard strings.
4. Try PagerFanta.

Comment: about second point. Try to use XHprof (facebookish php profiler) and watch how many times Doctrine:UnitOfWork is requested ;)
This is Madenss.